# Expected distance of a dart to the center of board

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have a dart board of radius R. You hit a dart. What is the expected **distance** of your hit with respect to the center of the board?

Attempt:

Let $x$= distance away from the center.

$E[X]=\int_{x=0}^{R}1-P(X\leq x) dx$

And $P(X\leq x)=x^2\pi/(\pi R^2)$

Do you guys think my approach is correct?

Comment: Yesterday this same question was posted under a different account. It was edited a few times, until it was _exactly_ the same letter-for-letter as this question, even with the same number of blank lines between paragraphs in the input text. About half an hour ago that question was deleted, and a minute later this one was posted. Did you temporarily lose access to your account and post under another? If so, for future reference, next time you run into a difficulty like that flag your question for moderator attention--they can probably fix the problem without deleting and reposting questions.

Comment: If you are also the owner of the account 'wrek' you might still want to ask the moderators to merge the accounts in order to move your other recent question to this account.

Comment: @kuku : can you help me understand why E[X] has (1-P(X<= x)) and not P(X=x) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct, although I would suggest using
the notation more carefully. In particular, if you are taking the
integral of something with multiple terms, put parentheses around
the expression to more clearly indicate you mean the integral of the
entire expression:
$$E[X]=\int_0^R (1-P(X\leq x)) \,dx.$$

Note that it is not necessary to write $x=0$ at the lower end of
the integral sign; the symbol $dx$ tells us that the integration is over
the variable $x.$

Comparing  your formula with [this other answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/13377),
keeping in mind that $F_X(x)$ in that other answer is the
same as your $P(X\leq x),$ we see that your formula is almost the same.
In fact, a standard formula for the expectation of
a random variable, when the variable takes only positive values, is

$$E[X]=\int_0^\infty (1-P(X\leq x)) \,dx.$$

In the problem you set out to solve,
$1 - P(X \leq x) = 0$ whenever $x \geq R,$ so
$$\int_R^\infty (1-P(X\leq x)) \,dx = 0$$

and therefore
$$\int_0^\infty (1-P(X\leq x)) \,dx
=\int_0^R  (1-P(X\leq x)) \,dx.$$

So you are justified in taking the integral only from $0$ to $R.$